# MapReduce partitioning issues in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm currently trying to use structs to hold variables of keys and values from a file. My string variable is a buffer that contains random words from a .sample file and filesize is the total number of bytes in that same file.

```
 struct keyValue{
    char* keystring;
    int value;
 };


int main(...){
...
/***** Split the input ****/
      struct keyValue split[numOfWords];
      int x;
      for(x=0; x<numOfWords;x++)
        {

          //split[x].keystring = wordRead(string,filesize);
          split[x].value = 1;
          //printf("this is your output %s\n",split[x].keystring);
        }
....
return 0; 
}
```

Here is my splitting function:

```
/**** Read word by word *****/

char * wordRead ( char* strings, unsigned long size){

  static int wordpointer=0;
  char* WordString;
  int i;
  for(i=0; wordpointer < size; wordpointer++,i++) {
    if ((strings[wordpointer] == ' ') )
      {
    //WordString[i+1]='/0';
    wordpointer++;
    break;
      }
    WordString[i]=strings[wordpointer];

  }

  printf("here is your word %s:\n",WordString);
  return WordString;

}
```

I keep getting Segmentation fault ( core dumped). I tried calling the functions a few time before the for loop and it sort of worked but the words overlap because char WordString is a pointer and previous letters over-lapped ex.

```
here is your word hello:
here is your word whylo:
```

How should dump out the pointer? Also any way I can get split[x].keystring to hold the strings from my wordRead function?

Comment: `WordString[i]=strings[wordpointer];` : Writing to the regions which are not reserved

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but every time the for loop runs it sets i back to 0

Comment: Space is required to store the substring. `WordString` should point the area reserved. but `WordString` isn't set.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I did char * WordString = (char*) malloc(50); but now my output is working a lot better but I'm getting weird symbols:                                            this is your output hello,1
this is your output why�`,1
this is your output isL�`,1
this is your output this`,1
this is your output happen,1
this is your output toL�`,1
this is your output meL�`,1
this is your output I�L�`,1
this is your output hate`,1

Comment: Cstring must be terminated by NUL(`'\0'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works a lot better with BLUEPIXY comment suggestion by allocating space for WordString with `malloc()`

Answer (score 0):

If the final character of `strings` is a space, you are reading past the end of the array by incrementing wordpointer and then requesting `strings[wordpointer]`.
I'd add a cautionary `trim` to the data before the splitting.

Comment: Doesn't the break take care of that issue?